# Using Ignite with create-react-native-app

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

In theory, it seems you should be able to use Ignite and its boilerplates with `create-react-native-app` by executing:

```
ignite attach
ignite add ir-boilerplate
```

And then copying the boilerplate application code into the project directory.

Now that `create-react-native-app` is tightly coupled with Expo, this doesn't work as expected. The Ignite code causes all kinds of errors within the Expo framework. From my reading, it seems the Ignite dependencies conflict with what is provided by Expo.

One lone soldier hacked together [a solution](https://github.com/skellock/expo-with-ignite) to the Expo conflicts, but this was done just for Expo and not `create-react-native-app`. Also I'd obviously prefer a more supported solution.

So... has anyone gotten the Ignite boilerplate running within the new `create-react-native-app` which integrates with Expo?

If that isn't feasible, what would you recommend? I think it's safe to assume that Ignite will have to be updated to support Expo, especially now that it is ingrained in `create-react-native-app`. If I develop using Ignite today, will I be able to migrate my work into the `create-react-native-app` framework when Ignite supports it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$ ignite new MyLatestCreation -b ignite-expo

(according to GitHub thread: https://github.com/infinitered/ignite/issues/1008)

Answer (score 2):

Hi, mate!
I'd recommend you this boilerplate to integrate expo with ignite: https://github.com/skellock/expo-with-ignite

Comment: It will be highly appreciated if you please us provide a small documentation to convert the existing ignite project to expo.

Answer (score 0):

For easy reference: this command will get you a ignite-expo boiler template

```
ignite new MyLatestCreation -b ignite-expo
```

report any issues [here](https://github.com/jbosse/ignite-expo-boilerplate/issues)

Answer (score 0):

yes ignite it works with expo for react native apps you should use this command line

**npx ignite-cli new PizzaApp -b bowser --expo** to run new project using ignite browser
for more information and how to work with it you can check my github readme for my first project using ignite [ignite]https://github.com/HAFDIAHMED/Ignite_first_app